# How to accept the answer on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accepting answers, what is it all about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about)

Many people aks me to accept the answer on Stack Overflow. I never know that I can. Now I don't know how to accept the answer? Where is this option?

Comment: That's not actually an exact duplicate; he's not asking why but how, and that post doesn't cover that.

Comment: @silky If you read the link you'll see that it explains how.

Comment: @silky - I have removed the offending comments. If you have any issues with the way I do moderate please take it up with Jeff and the team privately. Thanks.

Comment: I would think that one can judge such matters within himself.

Answer (score 14):

Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows).

As the author of the question, you'll see an outline of a checkmark on the left side of each answer. It'll be right below the up and down vote arrows. Click the checkmark next to the post that best answers your question to accept that answer as the best one.

Comment: +1 for the clever context-aware rep boosting attempt :)

Comment: +1 Thank you for answering this.  I find the checkmark a very non-intuitive and BAD UX.  I didn't know how to do this either until I read this post.  Such a simple thing should be WAY more obvious.  They should at least put the text "Accept this answer" below the checkmark imho.

Answer (score 5):

Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.