# How do I accept answers to my questions?

Tags: support, accept-rate, accepted-answer

Some of you tell me that I have not accepted your answers on my problems, or it is my 0% accept rate. Trust me, it is a technical problem.  I did not know what to do to get better answers. Please tell me what to do to accept all the answers that helped me very much. Can you explain to me what to do?  How do I accept the correct answers?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stackoverflow

Comment: LOL. Try the big V

Comment: The accept rating is updated in batch and can take quite a while to reflect your activity.  Hang in there, it will be updated after a bit.

Comment: @Brian - that one's closed as a duplicate. This one is the "master" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Harmen: I think that you mean the big **✔**

Answer (score 2):

Look at your activity, you have accepted exactly 0 answers. (And it shows on your username tag when you post "0% accept rate").

It is discouraging for people to put effort into answering your questions if you can't be bothered to accept their answers.

On each answer, there are huge outlines of check marks, all you need to do is click on one for each question.

Comment: @webdestroya: Accept ratings are updated in batch and can lag very far behind.

Comment: @Eric J. - Yea I know, but if you look at his answer history, he hasnt accept any at all. So his accept rate jives with his actual history.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of your previous Questions from here https://stackoverflow.com/users/322247/davit-datuashvili then just revisit your questions and click the tick icon on the left of an answer to accept it (if the question is actually resolved). You can also upvote other helpful responses by using the up arrow on the left.